# Verify that $\sin(\frac{A}{2})\sin(\frac{B}{2})\sin(\frac{C}{2})\le\frac{1}{8}$ in a general triangle $\triangle ABC$

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, inequality, contest-math, euclidean-geometry

So, this problem is inspired by a contest preparation problem I saw back in Japan, and it is as follows:

> In a general triangle $\triangle ABC$, show that $\sin(\frac{A}{2})\sin(\frac{B}{2})\sin(\frac{C}{2})\le\frac{1}{8}$

Now, while I still haven't figured out a geometric interpretation of this inequality, here is my attempt to prove this:

Recall that:

$$\sin^2(\frac{A}{2})=\frac{(1-\cos(A))}{2}$$

$$\sin^2(\frac{A}{2})=\frac{1}{2}(1-\frac{b^2+c^2-a^2}{2bc})$$

$$\sin^2(\frac{A}{2})=\frac{1}{2}(\frac{a^2-b^2-c^2+2bc}{2bc})$$

$$\sin^2(\frac{A}{2})=\frac{a^2-(b-c)^2}{4bc}$$

Now, obviously $\frac{a^2-(b-c)^2}{4bc} \le \frac{a^2}{4bc}$, therefore:

$$\sin^2(\frac{A}{2}) \le \frac{a^2}{4bc}$$

$$\sin(\frac{A}{2}) \le \frac{a}{2\sqrt{bc}}$$

This can be done for $\sin(\frac{A}{2}), \sin(\frac{B}{2})$ and $\sin(\frac{C}{2})$.

$$\sin(\frac{A}{2}) \le \frac{a}{2\sqrt{bc}}$$

$$\sin(\frac{B}{2}) \le \frac{b}{2\sqrt{ac}}$$

$$\sin(\frac{C}{2}) \le \frac{c}{2\sqrt{ab}}$$

Therefore:

$$\sin(\frac{A}{2})\sin(\frac{B}{2})\sin(\frac{C}{2}) \le (\frac{a}{2\sqrt{bc}})(\frac{b}{2\sqrt{ac}})(\frac{c}{2\sqrt{ab}})$$

$$\sin(\frac{A}{2})\sin(\frac{B}{2})\sin(\frac{C}{2}) \le \frac{abc}{8abc}$$

$$\sin(\frac{A}{2})\sin(\frac{B}{2})\sin(\frac{C}{2}) \le \frac{1}{8}$$

However I'm not sure if this is correct or if it is, I don't think this brute force approach is good. Are there any better options to prove this inequality? Please share your answers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To add some more insight, there is indeed a geometric intepretation of this inequality.

[image]

As shown in the picture, $AI$ is an angle bisector. $$\sin{A\over 2}={BH\over AB}\leq {BI\over AB} = {CI\over AC} = {BC\over AB+AC}$$

Therefore, with similar argument for $B$ and $C$ angles,

$$\sin{A\over 2}\sin{B\over 2}\sin{C\over 2}\leq{AB\cdot BC\cdot CA \over (AB+AC)(BA+BC)(CA+CB)}\leq {AB\cdot BC\cdot CA \over (2\sqrt{AB\cdot AC})(2\sqrt{BA\cdot BC})(2\sqrt{CA\cdot CB})}={1\over 8}$$

Answer (score 2):

Being angles of the triangles, the sines are all positive so we can use AM-GM inequallity:

$$
\left(\frac{\sin\left(\frac{A}{2}\right)+\sin\left(\frac{B}{2}\right)+\sin\left(\frac{C}{2}\right)}{3}\right)^{3}
\geq
\sin\left(\frac{A}{2}\right)\sin\left(\frac{B}{2}\right)\sin\left(\frac{C}{2}\right)
$$

The sine function is convex in the range of $[0,\frac{\pi}{2}]$ so we can use the convex inequality:

$$
\sin\left(\frac{\frac{A}{2}+\frac{B}{2}+\frac{C}{2}}{3}\right)
\geq
\frac{\sin\left(\frac{A}{2}\right)+\sin\left(\frac{B}{2}\right)+\sin\left(\frac{C}{2}\right)}{3}
$$

Then simply combine them and use $A+B+C=\pi$

Comment: Sine, convex? ${}{}{}$

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut ah it should have been concave in that interval eh? I am so rusty

Comment: yup ;-) ${}{}{}{}$

Answer (score 1):

By your work
$$\prod_{cyc}\sin\frac{\alpha}{2}=\prod_{cyc}\sqrt{\frac{(a-b+c)(a+c-b)}{4bc}}=\frac{\prod\limits_{cyc}(a+b-c)}{8abc}\leq\frac{1}{8}$$
because $$abc-\prod\limits_{cyc}(a+b-c)=\sum_{cyc}(a^3-a^2b-a^2c+abc)=$$
$$=\sum_{cyc}(a^3-abc-b^2c-a^2c+2abc)=\sum_{cyc}(a-b)^2\left(\frac{a+b+c}{2}-c\right)=$$
$$=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{cyc}(a-b)^2(a+b-c)\geq0.$$
By the way, last inequality is true for any non-negatives $a$, $b$ and $c$, but it's another problem.